# Configure Brother HL-1212W wireless printer via Ubuntu

Tags: networking, printing

I've been able to configure my Brother HL-1212W to print via USB cable without much problem.

The printer is not connected to the wireless network, but it is capable of it. I'd like to do the full configuration from Ubuntu (setting up the name and password of the wireless connection included)

I am running ubuntu 16.04

Comment: open the PRINTERS folder; click ADD; there should be a button for network printer; expand that; click on find network printer; does it find your network printer and offer to configure it for you?

Comment: the printer is not yet connected to the wireless network (ammended the answer to add that)

Comment: so are you able (with the help of Google?) to connect the printer to the network?

Comment: yes, but only using the windows "assistant". And I no longer have windows

Comment: well the printer should still be talking to the router; does the HL-1212 have a screen? can you look for network in that screen to confirm? How about just doing as in yesterday's post: open PRINTERS folder; click ADD; let it look and see if it finds 1212 as a network printer ..

Answer (score 0):

This link made everything work: [instructions](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/15); [instructions backup link](https://archive.fo/qKcpY), with one unfortunate exception (see end of the answer)

**To get the printer to work wirelessly:**

1. Download the installer for your printer (either searching for it or navigating the categories): http://support.brother.com/g/b/productsearch.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&content=dl
2. Unzip  it (`gunzip file` from the command line interface).
3. Run the file as root (`sudo  bash file`)
4. Answer the questions: hl-1212w for printer name; yes to set device URI; auto for the selection of URI
5. Reset your computer

Unfortunately, according to the link, the **initial setup that connects the printer to your wi-fi router** has to be done via windows.

Comment: Brother has amazing support for its printers under Linux.

Comment: The note at the bottom is the most important part in the answer "Unfortunately, according to the link, the initial setup that connects the printer to your wi-fi router has to be done via windows.". I can't reach a way to do it under linux.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the router and press the WPS or AOSS button until the light start to blink, go to the printer and press the translucid button until the light start to blink faster.
After a moment the printer will print a page to show the success of the internet connection.
I didn't install anything, just go to the settings, printers, add the printer and start to print.

I don't but if you need you can go to the [support.brother.com page](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=br&lang=pt&prod=hl1212w_us_eu&os=128&flang=English) and follow the instructions for the ''Driver Install Tool''.

So yes, it is possible to connect the printer to the WiFi without Windows.

Comment: solved everything in less than 2 seconds, thanks

Comment: this script has nothing to do wifi with connecting to wifi network. this only setup drivers for USB printing

Answer (score -1):

Brother lists its troubleshooting documents for the HL-1212W here.

https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=hl1212w_us_eu&ftype3=2039

I tried in the past to configure monochrome laser printers from Brother using wireless.  I remember that you have to plug the USB cable to the printer and a computer while doing the network configuration, but I always just used a connected laptop when I wanted to print.