# Brother Printer driver install without Internet?

Tags: drivers, internet, printing, brother

Ubuntu 16.04, Acer i5, 6GB, 256GB-SSD

Hi, I have a headless PC now with a Brother HLL2340DW printer attached via USB. I need to install the Brother drivers but the process needs Internet access. I do not want to have to drive 30-miles each way to the PC+printer and bring them back, install then take them back out.

I found this, 
[Configure Brother HL-1212W wireless printer via Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969205/configure-brother-hl-1212w-wireless-printer-via-ubuntu)
 and downloaded the files to a USB but it gets part way through and asks for a Proxy because of no Internet. It will not proceed beyond that. Thanks Brother printers!

I tried just using the Ubuntu Setup to install but nothing prints even though it thinks it is setup. It shows up in the "File > Print" Menu lists but nothing prints.

Is there some way to install the Brother drivers with Internet access? There is no cell signal where the PC+printer is.

If not, can anyone suggest a low-ish-cost printer that **will install** without direct Internet connection? Last damn Brother I will buy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this page http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=nz&lang=en&prod=hll2340dw_us_eu_as&os=128 lists the appropriate drivers for your printer. This page on installing the lpr driver http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=nz&lang=en&prod=hll2340dw_us_eu_as&os=128 gives more details: so you only need the lpr driver it seems; 0.03MB file and if you also do the cups driver it is 0.02MB so if you install the drivers; then from the PRINTERS folder select ADD NEW it should search for and find this HLL2340DW

Comment: Thanks, but that is the same data links as in the link I supplied above. I have spent around three hours **before** asking here and tried pretty much everything obvious. I had already tried downloading the .debs and installing them with Synaptic but it would not print. It seems Brother has a my-way or the highway attitude to driver installs and insisting on a live Internet connection -- totally worthless idea.